# Mongodb get record from specific month

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using mongo java driver mongo-java-driver-2.12.4.jar     **with mongodb 3.4**
I would like to find a printer inspection of a specific month (say August 08)
For some reason the query is not returning any results.
I need the code to be java compatible (driver-2.12.4)

sample db:  https://mongoplayground.net/p/b57Ch8h0lPU

basically in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM printerInspections  WHERE MONTH(inspectionDate) = X 
                                  and inspectionDeleted =false
```

current code:

```
DBObject getInspectionOfMonth(String printerId,int month){
        DBCollection collection = mongoTemplate.getCollection("printerInspections");

        DBObject clause1 = new BasicDBObject("inspectionDeleted", false);
        DBObject clause2 = new BasicDBObject("printerId", printerId);
        DBObject clause3 = new BasicDBObject("inspectionDate", "{$month:"+month+"}");

        BasicDBList andClause = new BasicDBList();
        andClause.add(clause1);
        andClause.add(clause2);
        andClause.add(clause3);

        BasicDBObject b = new BasicDBObject("$and", andClause);

        DBObject dBObject = collection.findOne(b);
        return dBObject;
        }
```

Comment: Please while asking a question add sample database collection and input/output expected, it helps in better understanding the question

Answer (score 1):

Change your clause3 :

```
DBObject monthClause = new BasicDBObject("month", month);
DBObject clause3 = new BasicDBObject("inspectionDate", monthClause);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is certainly in `clause3` as we are comparing `Date` with a `String`. For example, if the month is passed as 8, the computed string would become `"{$month: 8}"`.

**The requirement here is to fetch the month from `inspectionDate` and compare it with the passed `month` parameter.**

So the correct `clause3` would be the following:

```
DBObject clause3 = new BasicDBObject("$expr",
                new BasicDBObject("$eq", Arrays.asList(new BasicDBObject("$month", "$inspectionDate"), month)));
```

Comment: its throwing: UncategorizedMongoDbException: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue: unknown top level operator: $expr; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoException: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue

Comment: @user648026 Which mongo version are you using?

Comment: Mongodb version  3.4

Comment: We can use $expr with 3.6